# Yii2 как при настройке defaultRoute показывать полный путь в URL?

Tags: yii2

При использовании defaultRoute пропадает контролер и экшен в URL.

'defaultRoute' => 'show/show-all-movie',

Url: http://localhost/Yii2/web
Мне необходимо, что бы при загрузке странице и срабатывал это правило и Url  был бы  http://localhost/Yii2/web/show/show-all-movie

Answer (score 0):

'defaultRoute' не покажет вам путь в url. Вам необходимо сделать дефолтное правило, которое вызовет дефолтный метод и в нем сделать редирект на /show/show-all-movie

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая ответ madfan41k решение проблемы: создаем в контроллере метод редирект, который будет дефолтным:

`public function actionRedirect() {
        {
    return $this->redirect(['show/show-all-movie']);
}`

И прописываем в web.php дефолтное правило

`defaultRoute' => 'show/show-all-movie`

Теперь при загрузки страницы срабатывает нужные метод и в URL прописывается контроллер и экшен.